# Android sqlite database error IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to delete data from sq-lite database, data is loaded in custom list-view with check-box. When user check some check-box and then press delete button then it should delete all those data which is checked.

Everything is working fine it is deleting all data which is checked. But the problem is occurring at last two data. When last 2 data is remaining, and if i select both data for deleting then it is giving error.

Logcat is below

```
12-16 12:55:51.049: E/AndroidRuntime(11489): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-16 12:55:51.049: E/AndroidRuntime(11489): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:     Invalid index 1, size is 1
12-16 12:55:51.049: E/AndroidRuntime(11489):    at   java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
12-16 12:55:51.049: E/AndroidRuntime(11489):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
12-16 12:55:51.049: E/AndroidRuntime(11489):    at iqualtech.skirr.Classes$1$1.onClick(Classes.java:98)
12-16 12:55:51.049: E/AndroidRuntime(11489):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:169)
12-16 12:55:51.049: E/AndroidRuntime(11489):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-16 12:55:51.049: E/AndroidRuntime(11489):    at   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
12-16 12:55:51.049: E/AndroidRuntime(11489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
12-16 12:55:51.049: E/AndroidRuntime(11489):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 12:55:51.049: E/AndroidRuntime(11489):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-16 12:55:51.049: E/AndroidRuntime(11489):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
12-16 12:55:51.049: E/AndroidRuntime(11489):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
12-16 12:55:51.049: E/AndroidRuntime(11489):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and my delete function is as below

```
private void deleteMenuSpinner() {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Classes.this);

            final Spinner spinnerDelete = new Spinner(Classes.this);
            alertDialog.setView(spinnerDelete);

            adapterSpinner = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Classes.this,
                    R.array.delete_menu,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapterSpinner
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerDelete.setAdapter(adapterSpinner);

            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            Code.i = true;
                            int len = mListView.getCount();
                            SparseBooleanArray checked = mListView
                                    .getCheckedItemPositions();
                            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                                if (checked.get(i)) {
                                    Code.i = false;
                                    String[] delete = names2.get(i);
                                    String idString = delete[0];
                                    long idLong = Long.valueOf(idString);
                                    Log.d("Deleting...", idLong + "");
                                    dataManipulator.delete(idLong);
                                    names2.remove(i);
                                }
                            if (Code.i == true) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        Classes.this);
                                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("No Data");
                                alertDialogBuilder
                                        .setMessage(
                                                "No Data Available to Delete")
                                        .setCancelable(false)
                                        .setPositiveButton(
                                                "Ok",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(
                                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                                            int id) {
                                                    }
                                                });
                                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder
                                        .create();
                                alertDialog.show();
                            } else {
                                names2 = dataManipulator.selectAll();
                                stg1 = new String[names2.size()];
                                int x = 0;
                                String stg;

                                for (String[] name : names2) {
                                    stg = "Class Name : " + name[1];
                                    stg1[x] = stg;
                                    x++;
                                }
                                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                        Classes.this,
                                        R.layout.custom_list_item_multiple_choice,
                                        stg1);
                                mListView
                                        .setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                                mListView
                                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.assignmentheader);
                                mListView
                                        .setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                                mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

It is giving error on below line

```
String[] delete = names2.get(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:     Invalid index 1, size is 1
```

> It is giving error on below line
>
> ```
> String[] delete = names2.get(i);
> ```

The `names2` arraylist has just one element (size 1) but you're trying to `get()` the second one (index 1).

The code doesn't show how you set up your `names2` list but anyway the `len` constraint for `i` index looping comes from `mListView.getCount()` which possibly isn't correct.

Comment: So what is the solution, i mean where do i need to change.